# How to pass custom parameters to custom log appender

Tags: logging, log4net

I have created a custom log appender. This is from the default `Sitecore.Logging.dll`.

```
public class ApiLogger : log4net.Appender.ForwardingAppender
{
   public ApiLogger()
   {
     LogProperties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
   }

   public ApiLogger(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> logProperties)
   {
     LogProperties = logProperties;
   }

   public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> LogProperties { get; set; }

   protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   {
       ///Send log to 3rd Party API
   }
}
```

and declared it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:security="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/security/">
  <sitecore>    
    <log4net>
      <appender name="SeqLogger" type="MyApp.ApiLogger, MyApp" patch:after = "appender[@name='LogFileAppender']">            
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" />
        <encoding value="utf-8" />
      </appender>
      <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="ApiLogger" patch:after = "*[@ref='LogFileAppender']"/>
      </root>
    </log4net>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This is the calling method

```
public ActionResult UpdateOrder()
{
   try
   {
      ///update order
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     Log.Error("", ex, this);
   }
}
```

When there is an error, the default Sitecore log.txt is created and after that, the `Append()` method is triggered, where I'm sending the log info to a 3rd party API.

This custom logging is working fine & I'm able to view the exception details in the 3rd Party portal.

However, on an error, I would like to also capture the "Order" details like Id, Name etc.
The `LogProperties` was created for this but don't know how to use it.

The reason, I'm not calling the API directly in the `UpdateOrder()` method is, there are several other methods in the solution which have their respective details to be captured.

One approach I could think of is, passing a JSON string as the first parameter in the `Log.Error()` method, but then it's not possible to know if that string is a collection of properties or any custom message.

Is there a way to add the custom data to the `LoggingEvent` in the caller method itself, or any better way to achieve what I'm trying to.

Answer (score 1):

I know it might not be the direct answer that you are looking for but it will provide you with some ideas or lead you closer to a possible way. You can explore `conversionPattern` to pass additional parameters.

In this case, It just adds this information to the existing (default) LogFileAppender. To do this, extended Sitecore’s `SitecoreLogFileAppender` class as follows:

```
public class SitecoreLogFileAppenderEx : log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender
{
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        var properties = loggingEvent.Properties;
 
        properties["scuser"] = string.Empty;
        properties["scitemid"] = string.Empty;
        properties["rawurl"] = string.Empty;
 
        // Only log ERRORS or higher level events
        if (Sitecore.Context.Site != null && loggingEvent.Level >= Level.ERROR)
        {
            if (Sitecore.Context.User != null)
                try { properties["scuser"] = Sitecore.Context.User.Name; }
                catch { }
            if (Sitecore.Context.Item != null)
                try { properties["scitemid"] = Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString(); }
                catch { }
 
            try { properties["rawurl"] = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetServerUrl() + Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetRawUrl(); }
            catch { }
        }
        base.Append(loggingEvent);
    }
}
```

Then modified the web.config log4net configuration to use appender and added the custom properties to the PatternLayout as follows.:

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppenderEx, Sitecore.Drexel.Logging">
    <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/log.{date}.txt"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%4t %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c [%P{scuser} %P{scitemid} %P{rawurl}] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

It is important to note that when specifying the parameters in the PatternLayout, you must use a capital “P”.

References: https://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/adding-custom-parameters-to-the-log/

https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/log4net-configuration-logging/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you but I'm not logging to a text file. scuser,item are global props and there is no need for pattern. I could do it directly in the Append method. In my case, I need to send specific props for example, of an order whose details keep changing and has to be passed at the caller method level.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the below method. I got this example from a blog post where the need is to add username and URL to the log information.

So created a custom `LogFileAppender` worked for it.

Create a custom Appender that will inherit from the `RollingFileAppender` used by the default Appender.

```
public class CustomerInfoSitecoreLogFileAppender : log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
{
    protected override void Append(log4net.spi.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)  
    {  
 
     
    }  
}
```

Add the additional information using this. In this example we are passing logged in user information.

```
var user = AuthenticatedUserRepository.GetAuthenticatedUser();   
log4net.spi.LoggingEventData data = loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData();   
var username = string.IsNullOrEmpty(user?.Name) ? "User not logged in" : user.Name;   
data.Message += $"\r\nLogin: {username}\r\nUrl: {HttpContext.Current?.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri}";   
log4net.spi.LoggingEvent ev = new log4net.spi.LoggingEvent(data);   
base.Append(ev);
```

And use this patch file.

```
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/env/">  
  <sitecore>  
   <log4net>  
     <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">  
       <patch:attribute name="type">YOUR.NAMESPACE.CustomerInfoSitecoreLogFileAppender, YOUR.DLL</patch:attribute>  
     </appender>  
   </log4net>  
  </sitecore>  
 </configuration>
```

So using `loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData` you can pass your custom information and log this.

Hope this will give you some context.

Refer to this article for whole implementation.

https://www.sitecored.com/2020/07/add-username-to-sitecore-log.html

Comment: Could you pls explain how is this `Append()` different from the one in question. I can get the user & url details in my `Append()` method also..right? How can I pass an `Order` object, when there is an exception in the `UpdateOrder()` method. This means, I need to somehow access the `LoggingEvent` in the controller itself. Hope you got my question now.

Comment: @sukesh If you check the code how they are passing the data using `LoggingEventData`. So I can suggest that you can use this one in your catch block and bind your data (in string format) and then you can get it in your logging event.